# Reading images imported into NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, imageicon, netbeans-platform

I have imported images into my NetBeans project:
[image: project file tree]

I'm trying to read the image path and want to display them on JLabels using the `scaleImage()` method.

My code:

```java
public Home() {
    initComponents();
    scaleImage(img1, "/Images/Background_Image.jpg");
}

public void scaleImage(JLabel label, String imagePath) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(imagePath));
    Image img = icon.getImage();
    Image imgScale = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
    label.setIcon(scaledIcon);        
}
```

However, i keep getting errors `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I tried another way, but still prompting errors `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`:

```java
public void scaleImage(JLabel label, String imagePath) {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Home.class.getResource(imagePath));
        Image imgScale = image.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScale);
        label.setIcon(scaledIcon);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle any exception that may occur during image loading
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any better idea? Thanx

Comment: [Load them as resources](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
The above will show you how to arrange the packages

Comment: To avoid making any changes in your code you can simply create a package called `Images` at the root and put your images in there

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the `resources` folder (src/main/resources) and put there your folder `Image` with the image file, I think this is the main problem. If it doesn't help try to use Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/Images/Background_Image.jpg")) to get the image